# RowReduce with parameter, strange output (?)

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am facing some "strange" (?) output when using RowReduce with the following matrix

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2 \\
2 & k & 1 \\
k+1 & 6 & 5
\end{pmatrix}
$$

for it gives me the Identity matrix $\mathbb{1}_3$ as output.

I reduced it by hands and there is no way I get the identity matrix. Any help?

*Code*

```
In[21]:= RowReduce[{{1, 2, 2}, {2, a, 1}, {a+2, 6, 5}}] 

Out[21]= {{1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,0,1}}
```

Comment: Please, post _Mathematica_ code. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Done!

Comment: What result were you expecting, if not the identity?

Comment: From the documentation for `RowReduce`, "If m is a non-degenerate square matrix, RowReduce[m] is IdentityMatrix[Length[m]]" Perhaps your manual reduction has some problems.

Comment: @J.M.'sennui Why do you say so?

Comment: @xyzt Thank you!

Comment: A question is not an answer to my question. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the relevant mathematics.

Comment: FWIW there are 2 values of the parameter that give a different result: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=row+reduce+%7B%7B1%2C+2%2C+2%7D%2C+%7B2%2C+a%2C+1%7D%2C+%7Ba%2B2%2C+6%2C+5%7D%7D

Comment: @J.M.'sennui And your first question was not an answer to my initial question :)

Comment: Well, I asked a question because you neglected to make your question complete by mentioning what the expected correct answer was. Anyway, your question is closed, and I will not be commenting further.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually reduce your matrix by "by hand".
Consider the following :

We could make a linear combination with unknow coefficients of the 3 rows that give one row of the unit matrix. This will be 3 equations with 3 unknowns, that can be solved. This way, we will have to repeat this for every row of the unit matrix. However, to make llife easier, we can do this in one go:

```
m = {{1, 2, 2}, {2, a, 1}, {a + 2, 6, 5}};
cof = Array[Subscript[v, #1, #2] &, {3, 3}];
sol = cof /. Solve[cof.m == IdentityMatrix[3], Flatten[cof]][[1]];
sol.m // Simplify

(*{{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}*)
```